# Trying to get featured post thumbnail within edit function in Gutenberg WordPress

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

We are trying to get the post thumbnail from the selected post within Gutenberg Custom Block. So `selectedCoursePost.featured_media` returns `862` and media does exist with ID `862` but in the console we get `undefined` error.

Does someone know how we can get the post thumbnail from the `selectedCoursePost`?

Here is our code:

```
const { useSelect } = wp.data;
const { InspectorControls } = wp.blockEditor;
const { SelectControl, PanelBody } = wp.components;

export default {
    name: `hbosafe/course-grid-item`,
    title: `Course Grid Item`,
    icon: `button`,
    category: `common`,
    parent: ['hbosafe/course-grid'],
    attributes: {
        selectedCourse: {
            type: 'number',
        },
    },
    edit({ attributes, setAttributes }) {
        // querying courses
        const { courses } = useSelect((select) => {
            const { getEntityRecords } = select('core');

            // Query args
            const query = {
                status: 'publish',
                per_page: 10,
            };

            return {
                courses: getEntityRecords('postType', 'vsystems_course', query),
            };
        });

        // populate options for <SelectControl>
        let options = [];
        let selectedCoursePost;

        if (courses) {
            console.log(courses);
            options.push({ value: 0, label: 'Cursus selecteren' });
            courses.forEach((course) => {
                options.push({
                    value: course.id,
                    label: course.title.rendered,
                });
            });

            // Filter the posts array to find the specific course
            selectedCoursePost = courses.find(
                (post) => post.id === parseInt(attributes.selectedCourse, 10)
            );

            let featuredImageId;

            if (selectedCoursePost) {
                const media = wp.data
                    .select('core')
                    .getMedia(selectedCoursePost.featured_media);
                console.log(media);
            }
        } else {
            options.push({ value: 0, label: 'Loading...' });
        }

        return (
            <>
                <InspectorControls>
                    <PanelBody title="Cursus" initialOpen={true}>
                        <SelectControl
                            label="Cursus"
                            value={attributes.selectedCourse}
                            options={options}
                            onChange={(val) =>
                                setAttributes({ selectedCourse: Number(val) })
                            }
                        />
                    </PanelBody>
                </InspectorControls>

                <div>
                    {selectedCoursePost && selectedCoursePost.title && (
                        <div>
                            {selectedCoursePost.title.rendered}
                            <img src="" alt="" />
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </>
        );
    },
    save: ({ attributes }) => (
        <>
            <div>{attributes.selectedCourse}</div>
        </>
    ),
};
```

Thanks for you